# Firestore SDK for NodeJS CollectionReference.onSnapshot(querySnapshotCallback ... ) does it brings RT updates as it does on clients?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Does that means that my callback will get updates every time data changes in the DB even on the server side as long as the sdk firestore client is alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more specific, your callback will be invoked for as long as the listener is added, and the process stays alive.  You can expect the callback to get invoked [when the results of the query change over time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).  From the documentation:

> You can listen to a document with the onSnapshot() method. An initial call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot immediately with the current contents of the single document. Then, each time the contents change, another call updates the document snapshot.

You should [detach the listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) to stop this effect as needed.

If realtime results is not what you want, use `get()` instead to [fetch documents a single time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection).